# google cloud spanner parents, children, grandparents, grandchildren

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

some background:

I am building a schema where one account creates a session which is basically a payment and when some other account decides to pay a transaction is generated and the money is transferred to the account that initiated the session.

I want to be able to perform all kinds of queries on these table and I want this to be as efficient as possible.

I came up with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    accountId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    balance FLOAT64 NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(accountId);

CREATE TABLE session (
    accountId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    sessionId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    amount FLOAT64 NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(accountId, sessionId),
    INTERLEAVE IN PARENT account ON DELETE CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
    transactionId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    sessionId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    accountId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(sessionId, transactionId),
    INTERLEAVE IN PARENT session ON DELETE CASCADE;

CREATE INDEX PayersAccountForSession ON `transaction`(accountId),
    INTERLEAVE IN account
```

Suppose we have two accounts with id `account1` and `account2`. `account1` creates a session for 100€ with id `session` so we get a row `(account1, session, 100)` in the `session` table. and then `account2` decides to pay the 100€ and a transaction with id `transaction` is created giving us a row `(transaction, session, account2)` in the `transaction` table.

Right now this doesn't work because in the `transaction` table I have no reference to the `accountId` key from the parent table but in my case this `accountId` is a different id then the one in the session table.
I could do this:

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
    transactionId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    sessionId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    accountId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    payersAccountId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(sessionId, accountId, transactionId),
    INTERLEAVE IN PARENT session ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But now I haven't found any way to create an interleaved index for the `payersAccountId` to the account table because the name doesn't match any key column in that table. This seems kind of weird to me I think it should be possible to create interleaved indexes to columns with different names (maybe it is but I am missing something).

What I need is a way to resolve this in a way that keeps all account, sessions and transactions in the same split and to be able to query accounts of the payer and the receiver starting in the `transaction` table. Also I would like to know if there is any way to create multiple interleaved indexes in the same table but based on different columns like in the example for `accountId` and `payerAccountId`.

Thanks for taking your time :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to interleave tables if they don't match with the column name.

Adding the `payersAccountId` to the `transaction` table is a good idea, with this you could do a query matching the `payersAccountId` with the `sessionId` and the `accountid` like the following:

`SELECT * from account WHERE accountId = (SELECT payersAccountId FROM transaction WHERE sessionId = 1)`